# AppLocalization.of(context) alway return null on child class

Tags: flutter

I'm using `flutter_localizations` package for my app, on `ChildScreen`, when i call `AppLocalization.of(context)`,it alway return null, but when I call it in the `ParentScreen`, it still works fine.
This is my codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

void main() => runApp(const ParentScreen());

class ParentScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ParentScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ChildScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChildScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('context = $context');
    return Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.appName); //it caused null exception here
  }
}
```

I don't know where the issue is.